# Storing a boolean value on the server

Tags: php, apache

WordPress has this thing that examines whether it has been set up (installed) on the server and if it's not, it takes the visitor to a "install" page. I need to have something like that in a system I'm building.

I need to store a boolean value on the server.

What would be the most elegant / lightweight approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a semaphore, where you just create an empty file, and then you just check if the file exists as your TRUE value.

Comment: I believe so. That's how it works, a variable that doesn't really have a value to it, but it's presence means that it is "set".

Answer (score 1):

Most of the packages that require installation or configuration have different ways. Some can check if a file exists then return true or false, write to a database, or have a configuration file included in all its scripts. Most go with the `if(file_exists)` method.

EDIT :  [Dabr](http://code.google.com/p/dabr) has a `config_bla.php` file (with all the needed constants defined in the file) which should be renamed to `config.php` after installation.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
function was_here_before()
{
    $file="/some/writable/file.txt";
    if (file_exists($file))
        return true;
    else
    {
        touch($file)
        return false;
    }
}
```

There are many ways however, YMMV.